# Python Multithreading - where does keyboard interrupt go

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having trouble with some seemingly simple code which basically starts a thread to read a serial device, and then in the main thread writes some data to the device. The intended shutdown mechanism is a keyboard interrupt, but that doesn't seem to be caught how I expect.

```
readData = True
dev = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyX', 115200)
readThread = threading.Thread(target=read_loop, args=())
readThread.start()
send_loop()

def read_loop():
    while readData:
        try:
            print dev.read(2)
        except Exception, e:
            print 'Continue'
    dev.close()

def send_loop():
    global readData
    for i in xrange(5):
        try:
            dev.write('a')
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception,e:
            break
    readData = False
    readThread.join()
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be caught how I expect" mean, and what did you *actually* want to happen? I predict that you didn't account for the fact `dev.read` is a blocking operation with your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A keyboard interrupt, or any other external signal, always goes to the main thread only -- **not** to sub-threads.  If you want everything to stop when the main thread terminates, make sub-threads **daemons**, so they won't keep the whole process alive by themselves!